# I want to post the values that comes from checked product even the user leaves empty those fields

Tags: angular, express, mongoose

> I have a table to list products that user input.It has attribute to
>   update product features with an edit button.And displaying an
>   confirmation dialog panel(bootstrap model).In edit panel,I can gets
>   and display the values of checked product in input fields.But If some
>   input fields leaves empty,only the inputted field is updated. I want
>   to post the values that comes from checked product even the user
>   leaves empty those fields.
>
> **HTML
>   **

```
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" id="checked" (change)="selectCheckbox($event,product)" />
      </td>

      <td id="tableCat">{{product.category}}</td>
      <td id="tableName">{{product.name}}</td>
      <td id="tableDesc">{{product.description}}</td>
      <td id="tablePrice">{{product.price}}</td>

      <td>

        <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
            (click)="sendingValue()" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><i
              class="fas fa-edit fa-xs"></i></button>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
            data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i
              class="far fa-trash-alt fa-xs"></i></button></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

{{productUpdateForm.value|json}}
              
                
              
              
                
              
              

                
              
              
                
              
              
                
              
              
                Update

> GETTING CHECKED PRODUCT DATA .TS

```
chkSelected: Array<any> = [];
 selectedName: any;
  selectedDesc: any;
  selectedPrice: any;
  selectedCat: any;

  selectCheckbox(event, val) {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      this.chkSelected = val._id;
      this.selectedName = val.name;
      this.selectedDesc = val.description;
      this.selectedCat = val.category;
      this.selectedPrice = val.price;
    }
    //  else {
    //   const index = this.chkSelected.indexOf(val);
    //   this.chkSelected.splice(index, 1);
    // }
    console.log(this.chkSelected);
  }

  init() {

    this.productUpdateForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      _id: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

 UpdateProduct() {
    this.menuService.updateProduct(this.productUpdateForm.value).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.productUpdateForm.reset();
      this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
      jQuery('#edit').modal('hide');
    });
  }
  sendingValue() {
    jQuery('#updateName').val(this.selectedName);
    jQuery('#updateDesc').val(this.selectedDesc);
    jQuery('#updatePrice').val(this.selectedPrice);
    jQuery('#updateCat').val(this.selectedCat);
    console.log(this.selectedName);
  }
```

> SERVICE

```
 updateProduct(body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(BASEURL + '/menu/update-product/' + body._id, body);
  }
```

> ENDPOINT FOR UPDATING PRODUCT

```
 updateProduct(req, res) {
    Menu.update(
      { company: req.company._id, "products._id": req.params._id },
      {
        $set: {
          "products.$": {
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            price: req.body.price,
            category: req.body.category
          }
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    )
      .then(info => {
        res.status(httpStatus.OK).json({ message: "product updated", info });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res
          .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
          .json({ message: "product update error", err });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did it but I think it's not in a good way to code.. I used
>   [(ngModel)] for every update form field..But it warns me that :

```
**It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with**
```

I couldnt figure out how to solve this.